# Get ASP Page Method return from jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an aspx page. I want to call the ASP.NET method via jquery. I have implemented the code but the problem is that I am getting the HTML of whole page rather than getting the returned string from ASP method. I need some assistance.
Here is my code:

```
 [WebMethod]
        public string PopulateData(string coursename)
        {
    return "called";
    }
```

and here is the jquery method:

```
var subject = 'database';
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "CourseDetail.aspx/PopulateData",
            data: "{coursename:'" + subject + "'}",
            success: function (msg) {
                // Do something interesting here.
                alert('result : ' + msg);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in the contentType and dataType.

```
var subject = 'database';
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "CourseDetail.aspx/PopulateData",
        data: "{coursename:'" + subject + "'}",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Do something interesting here.
            alert('result : ' + msg);
        }
```

- contentType is the header sent to the server, specifying a particular format.
  Example: I'm sending json or XML
- dataType is telling jQuery what kind of response to expect.
  Expecting JSON, or XML, or HTML, etc....